# Print the version of lean that is running

Tags: lean4, beginner

In python, I can get the version of python I am using like this:

```python
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

> `3.11.0 (main, May 25 2023, 12:06:07) [GCC 12.2.0]`

How do I do the equivalent thing in Lean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#eval Lean.versionString
```

Alternatively, from the command line, you can invoke `lean -v` to print the version.

In Lake projects, there is a a file `lean-toolchain` that sets the version of Lean.